# How to update db by reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

i want to update a table instance by reflection

here is what i tried

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == TableName);


object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

foreach (var item in dic)
{

    PropertyInfo information = type.GetProperties()
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Key);

    information.SetValue(instance, item.Value.ToString(), null);

}
var fx = db.Set(instance.GetType());
fx.Add(instance);
result= db.SaveChanges();
```

its giving me following exception

```
   InnerException = {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
 'PK_primryKeyName. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'tableName'.
 The duplicate key value is (39).
\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

its seems Entity framework considers it as an insert rather than an update

Comment: How is the type defined? Does it have a comparer/Equals defined?

Comment: var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == TableName);

Comment: Not the variable, the actual type the object is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we handle things that are not attached without going back and getting it through manual select.

```
   var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
   .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "");


            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            foreach (var item in new Dictionary<string, string>())
            {

                PropertyInfo information = type.GetProperties()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Key);

                information.SetValue(instance, item.Value.ToString(), null);

            }               

            db.Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: could you please elaborate in the current context